# How can I traverse through my result?

Tags: clojure

This is what I currently have:

```
{:total-pages 1, :total-results 1, :items [{:item-atributes {:title Tolkien  Calendar 2017, :product-group Book, :manufacturer Harper Voyager, :author J. R.
R. Tolkien}, :SalesRank 12016, :item-links [{:description Technical Details, :url https://www.amazon.com/Tolkien-Calendar-2017-J-R/dp/tech-data/0062566938
%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938} {:description Ad
d To Baby Registry, :url https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0062566938%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401
-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938} {:description Add To Wedding Registry, :url https://www.amazon.com/gp/r
egistry/wedding/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0062566938%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D3
86001%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938} {:description Add To Wishlist, :url https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3D0062566938%26Su
bscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938} {:description Tell A
Friend, :url https://www.amazon.com/gp/pdp/taf/0062566938%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creati
ve%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938} {:description All Customer Reviews, :url https://www.amazon.com/review/product/0062566938%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI
6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938} {:description All Offers, :url https://ww
w.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0062566938%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D215401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26cre
ativeASIN%3D0062566938}], :detail-page-url https://www.amazon.com/Tolkien-Calendar-2017-J-R/dp/0062566938%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI6FVBZ4SCQ3VMGCQ%26tag%3D2
15401-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0062566938, :asin 0062566938}]}
```

I got this from a result and wanted to traverse through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not XML.  You can use [`get-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in) to traverse your nested structure.

Comment: I tried doing (print(get-in (amazon_search i)[:items :item-atributes :title]))) but it's returning nil to me. the amazon_search is my function that gets my nested structure

Comment: :items is an array.  can you get-in that much?

Comment: i got it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As @jmargolistvt said, you have a Clojure data structure (nested maps & arrays), not xml.

Also, next time please print using the `prn` instead of `println` or similar, as it is important to keep the double-quote chars around strings like "Harper Voyager".

I simplified the data a bit, and have this:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require 
    [tupelo.core :as t] 
    [clojure.pprint :as pp]
    )
  (:gen-class))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def data
  {:total-pages 1, :total-results 1, :items 
   [ {:item-atributes 
          {:title "Tolkien  Calendar 2017", :product-group "Book", 
           :manufacturer "Harper Voyager" 
           :author "J. R.  R. Tolkien" }, :SalesRank 12016, :item-links [{:description "Technical Details" } ]
     } ] } )


(pp/pprint data)

(defn -main [& args]
)
```

which yields:

```
~/clj > lein run    
{:total-pages 1,
 :total-results 1,
 :items
 [{:item-atributes
   {:title "Tolkien  Calendar 2017",
    :product-group "Book",
    :manufacturer "Harper Voyager",
    :author "J. R.  R. Tolkien"},
   :SalesRank 12016,
   :item-links [{:description "Technical Details"}]}]}
```

At this point, you can add

```
(newline)
(doseq [item (data :items) ]
  (newline)
  (pp/pprint item)
  (newline)
  (spyx (item :SalesRank))
  (spyx (get-in item [:item-atributes :title])))
```

to get:

```
{:item-atributes
 {:title "Tolkien  Calendar 2017",
  :product-group "Book",
  :manufacturer "Harper Voyager",
  :author "J. R.  R. Tolkien"},
 :SalesRank 12016,
 :item-links [{:description "Technical Details"}]}

(item :SalesRank) => 12016
(get-in item [:item-atributes :title]) => "Tolkien  Calendar 2017"
```

Your `project.clj` must include this to make the `(spyx ...)` part work:

```
:dependencies [
  [tupelo "0.9.9"]  ...
```

Comment: I used @jmargolistvt 's way to extract the title and salesrank. I have about 10 books, and i'm getting title,salesrank from each of them. How can I sort the books based on salesrank, and then print them neatly in a table format?

Comment: I have it in this format right now.. (println(get-in (amazon_search isbn)[:items 0 :item-atributes :title]))
  (println(get-in (amazon_search isbn)[:items 0 :SalesRank]))